# Examples of subgroups where it's nontrivial to show closure under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, big-list

Usually when a subgroup is declared, it is trivial (or at least straightforward to a sophomore) to prove that it is a subgroup under multiplication. For example:

- Homomorphic image and preimage of a subgroup
- Center
- Intersection of two subgroups
- Stabilizer of a point in a group action
- Elements of finite conjugacy class
- $HN$, where $H\leq G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$

I'm looking for interesting theorems where a subset is claimed to be a subgroup, but it is nontrivial to verify. I am looking for some kind of structure-theoretic subgroup that can be defined for any group (or a large class of groups), rather than specific examples that are hard to show closure.

---

I can think of only one example.

Let $\Delta(G)$ be those elements with finite conjugacy class (easily seen to be a subgroup), and let $\Delta^+(G)$ be its torsion subset. Note that $g$ has finite conjugacy class in $G$ if and only if $[G:C(g)]<\infty$ where $C(g)$ is the centralizer.

$$\Delta^+(G):=\{g\in G : |\langle g\rangle|<\infty, [G:C(g)]<\infty\}.$$

> **Theorem:** *$\Delta^+(G)$ is closed under multiplication.*

The proof takes 1-2 pages of nontrivial calculations. If $a,b$ are torsion, it's not true that their product $ab$ is torsion --- but amazingly, it *is* true if $a,b$ have only finitely many conjugates.

Does anyone have any other examples?

---

*Proof of the Theorem, for those interested.* You can see it from the following (nontrivial) lemma.

> **Lemma** (Dietzmann). *If $[G:Z(G)]<\infty$, then $[G,G]$ is finite.*

Modulo the (page long) proof of this, let's see why it implies the theorem.

Let $x,y\in \Delta^+(G)$ so that $x,y$ have finite conjugacy classes and orders. Clearly $xy$ has a finite conjugacy class, so we just have to show that it has finite order.

Let $N$ be the subgroup generated by all the conjugates of $x$ and $y$, so that $N$ is finitely-generated. Then $N/N'$ is an abelian group generated by finitely many torsion elements, hence finite, so $[N:N']<\infty$. It is thus enough to show $N'$ is finite, because then $N$ is finite, and since $xy\in N$ this completes the proof.

To show $N'$ is finite we use Dietzmann's Lemma: notice $Z(N)=C_N(x)\cap C_N(y)$, and these centralizers have finite index in $N$. Therefore $[N:Z(N)]<\infty$ and we apply Dietzmann's Lemma.

This was already a somewhat lengthy and interesting argument, and we haven't even proved Dietzmann's Lemma yet!

---

*Edit:* a related question is as follows. Name any functions $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ that are homomorphisms, but it is nontrivial to show.

Comment: The set of torsion elements in a nilpotent group is a subgroup. And the set of elements of order some power of a prime $p$, in a nilpotent group, is a subgroup.

Comment: The set of exponentially distorted elements in a simply connected solvable Lie group is a subgroup.

Comment: @YCor: AFAIK $\Delta(G)$ is the FC center and your argument shows it is a subgroup, but $\Delta^+(G)$ is just the torsion set and it is even harder to show this is a subgroup. I included a proof sketch in an edit.

Comment: You're right. Sorry I was puzzled by unusual notation.

Comment: I don't remember the precise statement, but there is a theorem that looks like "let the finite group $G$ act transitively on the finite set $X$ such that every element of $G$ has at most one fixed point. Then the set of elements of $G$ that have no fixed point + $e$ is a subgroup of $G$" - if I remember correctly, the proof uses representation theory

Comment: Very cool @Max. If you have the time to do a write-up and include it as an answer, that would be lovely!

Comment: I would write an answer but I have to find the precise statement first !

Comment: You don't need any use of structure theorem for f.g. abelian groups (clearly every f.g. abelian group generated by torsion elements is finite).

Comment: @Ycor: Fair enough.

Comment: I don't know if it qualifies, but it is a very difficult and recent theorem (positive solution to Ore's conjecture) that the set of commutators in every finite simple group is a subgroup.

Comment: @YCor That's exactly the type of thing I'm looking for!

Comment: I was wondering if it qualifies, because while it is hard, it is of no use to "construct" a subgroup, since it just produces a subgroup which was trivial to define in other terms. On the other hand, my second comment defines a subgroup in simply connected solvable Lie groups that is important and not obvious to define in other terms (although it's possible).

Comment: Yes, and I was thinking of how to explanation the "qualification". But I am preferring general constructions (e.g. yours and Max's) over specific examples (e.g. the matrix one below, although they are interesting), and accessibility is always important (~ one course in group theory). Sorry for not saying all this in the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A particularly nice example is the following : suppose the finite group $G$ acts on the finite set $X$ in such a way that every nontrivial element of $G$ has at most one fixed point. Let $S$ be the set of elements of $G$ that have no fixed points. Then $H=S\cup \{1\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I believe the only known proofs are representation-theoretic (or at least that was the case at first).

Comment: Such groups are called *Frobenius groups*, and the subgroup in question is the *Frobenius kernel*. It was proved to be a subgroup (using representation theory) by Ftrobenius in 1901. More recently, Thompson proved that this subgroup is nilpotent.

Comment: For those who don't know about John G. Thompson: "more recently" means that he proved it in his PhD thesis 1959.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n\geq 2$ letters. The alternating group $A_n$ is the subgroup of $S_n$ given by all even permutations of $S_n$.

One proof uses the signum or sign function $s:S_n\rightarrow\{\pm 1\}$ which assigns to a permutation $\pi$, $+1$ if $\pi$ is even, and $-1$ if $\pi$ is odd.
It can be shown that the sign function is a homomorphism, i.e., $s(\pi\sigma) = s(\pi)\cdot s(\sigma)$.

It follows that the product of two even permutations is even and so the multiplication in $A_n$ is well-defined.

Comment: Ah yeah, this is a tricky one too. You can also use determinant of the associated permutation matrix (considered over $\mathbf{F}_2$) to construct the sign function, which makes it "easy" to show that it's a homomorphism and its kernel is a subgroup of index $2$, hence normal.

Comment: When I first took group theory, the instructor painstakingly showed that if a permutation is a product of transpositions, then the number of such transpositions is unique modulo $2$. I'm not sure if using determinants properly circumvents this technical argument, or sweeps it under the rug.

Comment: @Ehsaan: I don't think determinants over $\mathbb{F}_2$ will help you much...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sorry you're right, don't know what I was thinking. Do it over $\mathbf{Q}$ and argue it is $\pm 1$.

Comment: I think that the problem here really is to define an even permutation.

Comment: To even define the determinant you need permutations and the signature at one point or another (for instance to show that the dimension of the space of alternating forms is what it should be). I think the best way to define the signature and related things is to first prove that there is at most one nontrivial morphism $S_n\to \mathbb{C}^\times$, that it has to be  $-1$ on transpositions; and then just give the definition in terms of products

Comment: An even (resp. odd) permutation is a product of an even (resp. odd) number of transpositions. The hard part is showing that no permutation is both even and odd.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=GL(4,k)$ (the group of all $4\times4$ invertible matrices with entries in a field $k$) and let $N$ be the subgroup of those matrices $M\in GL(4,k)$ of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\0&0&a_{33}&a_{34}\\0&0&a_{43}&a_{44}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think this one follows from the fact that 2x2 upper triangular matrices form a group and that you can operate matrices "blockwise".

Comment: Indeed it does, but many Linear Algebra students don't know that.